# MOMENTUM Scrolling is laggy in Next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am building my portfolio  website in Next.js Typescript. I am new to Next.js and Typescript. I just using them just for learning. In google chrome, smooth scrolling is very laggy. This isn't an issue in other browsers for some reason. I am using the code that I that found on YouTube. The code is open sourced so I cloned the repo and run it and it works just fine. There is no issue in Google Chrome as well. So I don't know what's wrong with it in my project

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next';
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
import Nav from '../components/nav';
import useMousePosition from '../hooks/useMousePosition';
import Projects from '../components/projects';
import Experience from '../components/experience';
import Contact from '../components/contact';

const Home: NextPage = () => {

  const size = useWindowSize();
  const app = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const scrollContainer = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const data = {
    ease: 0.1,
    current: 0,
    previous: 0,
    rounded: 0
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => skewScrolling());
  }, []);

  const setBodyHeight = () => {
    if (scrollContainer.current)
      document.body.style.height = `${scrollContainer.current.getBoundingClientRect().height}px`;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setBodyHeight();
  }, [size.height]);

  const skewScrolling = () => {

    if (scrollContainer.current) {
      data.current = window.scrollY;
      data.previous += (data.current - data.previous) * data.ease;
      data.rounded = Math.round(data.previous * 100) / 100;
      scrollContainer.current.style.transform = `translate3d(0, -${data.rounded}px, 0)`;
      requestAnimationFrame(() => skewScrolling());
    }

  };


  return (
    <div ref={app} className={styles.container}>

      <Head>
        <title>Abhijith Kannan</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <Nav />
 
      <div ref={scrollContainer} style={{ zIndex: 10 }}>
        <div className={styles.background}>
          <div className={styles.intro}>
            <img className={styles.backgroundImg} src="/images/back.svg" alt="background" />
            <div className={styles.introContainer}>
              <div className={styles.text}>
                <h2 className={styles.h2}>Hi everyone,</h2>
                <h1 className={styles.h1}>I am <span className={styles.span}>Electrical Engineering</span> and
                  <span className={styles.span}> Frontend Developer</span></h1>
              </div>
              <div></div>
            </div>
            <div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <Projects />
        <Experience />
        <Contact />
        <footer className={styles.footer}>Developed by Abhijith Kannan</footer>

      </div>
      {/* <BackgroundIcon /> */}
    </div >
  )
}

export default Home
```

You can view the problem just by going to this link : https://forgottentale.vercel.app/

useWindowSize hook code :

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function useWindowSize() {
  function getSize() {

    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      return {
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight
      };
    }
    else {
      return {
        width: 0,
        height: 0
      };
    }

  }

  const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState(getSize);

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleResize() {
      setWindowSize(getSize());
    }

    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
  }, []);

  return windowSize;
}
```

Comment: hi, I got the same problem! just wondering if you have solved yet?

Answer (score 0):

Scroll-behaviour: smooth is a css property you add to the body of your page.

Comment: That isn't the one i am referring to. I referring to smooth scroll in which we decrease the scroll velocity. I don't know if there is another name for it.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you are using rounded numbers. Did you try without the Math.round?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30213427)